# Use of a solenoid valve over a selector valve

Tags: aircraft-design, fuel-systems, fuel-tanks, reliability

When designing a low-wing light aircraft with two integral tanks at the wings and a collector tank in between, what type of valve should be used to allow the pilot to select the integral tank which will feed the collector tank in a reliable way? A *selector* valve or two [solenoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid) valves?

Fuel will be fed from the integral tanks to the collector tank via jet pumps with no moving parts, not gravity.

Comment: Hi Enes, welcome to this site. Are you asking about purely mechanical selector valve vs. electric solenoid valves?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am asking for

Comment: This question, the way it's written, is highly open to opinionated responses. The answer to this *or* question is "yes". It depends so much on the design. If it's an ultralight/LSA and this saves 500g which can then be moved into structure, then it's quite possibly critical choice. If it's a humdrum standard airplane where weight and complexity decisions don't arise because of regulatory limits, then the answer might be different. @EnesSenel, with this in light, could you reword this question to make it so there's a clear "right" and "wrong" answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's at least one strong reason to prefer manually operated valves over solenoid valves: they still work during a complete electrical failure.

Aircraft engines, due to magneto ignition, will continue to operate even with (for instance) an exploded battery, melted main ground cable, or other failure that kills the entire electrical system and can't be repaired in flight.  You'll have no landing lights, instrument lights, clearance lights, radios, or electical instruments -- but at least you'll have power, basic vacuum or airstream powered instruments (airspeed, altimeter, turn and bank, assuming these analog gauges are installed) and presumably if you have retract gear you have a manual method to lower it; therefore you can continue to fly and land the airplane (at least in daylight VFR conditions) -- but with solenoid valves, you may be limited to the fuel in the collector tank or, with a better design, you'll be on "both" willy-nilly or feeding from one wing without the ability to switch (leading to trim problems as fuel is depleted).

Bottom line, a fuel valve that works any time you can keep the engine run is better than one that quits if the master switch gets flipped.

Comment: Inability to shut off fuel flow in an emergency involving loss of electrics is frowned upon, to say the least. To create a setup that leaves fuel lines open with no electricity will keep fuel flowing and engine running, but you'd be essentially landing an incendiary bomb. Emergency landing procedures commonly list "fuel valve off/closed", I'm guessing this may very well be a regulatory issue as well: you'd need a fail safe (mechanical) fuel shutoff anyway.

Comment: I agree, though the shutoff need not be capable of selecting either tank or both in a dual tank setup -- but having the engine shut down for lack of fuel if the master breaker flips is nearly as bad (an avoidable forced landing is something I've understood to be undesirable).

Comment: Solenoids can have multiple stable positions. It's quite the big assumption that the designer is considering defaulting valves to "normally closed".

Comment: @KennSebesta Sure, but you're unable to change the state.  You may be stuck with a full right tank and dry left, and have to do a forced landing with a heavy wing because you can't switch feeds.

Comment: This is easily designed out by having valves which fail "normally open". Then an electrical system failure simply results in drawing from both wings. In every plane I've ever flown with a "both" selector, I've never once used one tank exclusively.

Comment: @ZeissIkon In principle I agree with the concern that electrically actuated valves can get stuck (although reasonable arguments could be made as to whether this is a "failure"), although the same thing can happen with a mechanical valve. As an aside, there's a lot of fear in aviation of complete electrical system failures, but now that people are paying attention to this aspect of design it looks like those problems are disappearing into the past.

Comment: @KennSebesta Well, like any other "whole aircraft" failure, it's not common, but if it happens, it can be really bad.  I did have a battery explode once, in a car, but it was on a start attempt, which would usually be a ground event in an aircraft, so would prevent flight rather than leave you stranded at altitude with most of the panel dead and no lights.  I agree, fail open with a separate mechanical shutoff would be the sensible way to design...

Answer (score 2):

You would use a solenoid or other electrically operated valve, like a torque motor operated one, only if you *must* use it remotely and it isn't practical to operate it mechanically.

In doing so you also have to provide redundancy in the form of a manual override (such as a cable you can operate that forces the valve open following an electrical failure in the valve or upstream of it, or a sticking solenoid), or dual valves in parallel (or whatever else you can design to eliminate safety-critical single-points-of-failure).

Solenoids like to stick and torque motors like to burn out, and even if the valve is spring loaded to be normally open so it is fail-passive in theory, I wouldn't trust my life to it without some form of backup.

In a light aircraft design where the components can be made to be easily in reach of the pilot, a manually operated selector valve, or manually operated shutoff valves at the wing roots is the way to go. There is simply no point in designing an electrically operated system when a simple and robust manual alternative is easily done.

My preferred design would be a left-right-both selector right at the collector tank entrance, a separate emergency shutoff valve at the firewall operated by its own remote mechanical control that sticks out and gets in the way of things when at OFF, and ideally, manually operated emergency shutoff valves at the tank outlets in each wing so that fuel is contained within the wing if it gets broken off in a crash (that may be overkill - I've never seen shutoff valves right at fuel tanks in light aircraft, but I'd do it if it was my own design).